# Android Studio & Kotlin - Database to use?

Tags: android, kotlin

Advise on which database on Android Studio and Kotlin

I am struggling on developing an app using Kotlin using Android Studio.
The app will have 50-100 keys/ids (lines) with each row containing ~10 pieces of data (name, dates, etc.), that can be searched through and the results shown on the app.
As I would like this to be fairly simple, what database should I be using? XML, SQLite, MySQL, etc? 
Are there any simple examples that I could use please?
Really appreciate any help.

Comment: Search for Room Database

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an offline/local database, you can use room DB instead of SQLite to avoid usage of too much boilerplate code to convert SQL queries and data objects.

You can check this link
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Many thanks! I'm looking at you're suggestion with Room. Cheers